# Deleting row from table and database PHP/MySQL via image button

Tags: php, html, mysql, delete-row

I am trying to call a function within a php file that will fire a query to delete a row from a table and the database but can't seem to get it working

here is the button:

```
<td><a href="../service/deleteModule.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img src="../web/img/delete.png" height='25' onclick="delete()" width='25' alt='delete'/></a></td>
```

Comment: And...!? **(¬_¬)"** . What is the problem?

Comment: Looks like you're going to need some JavaScript and PHP. Or do you have that already?

Comment: What is the current behavior, and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Well... shooting in the dark, your `<a>` tag seems wrong. Assuming this code is inside a `<?php` fix it with:  `<a href="../service/deleteModule.php?id=".$row['id']." ">`

Comment: public function delete($deletemodule){
        
        return $this->moduleDao->deleteModule($deletemodule);
    }   the onclick="delete()" function call doesn't get called, it is in a different file to the html code

Comment: This information won't help us...

Answer (score 2):

You could use an XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript.

myWebpage.html

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        // Row deleted successfully
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "deleteRow.php?rowWhichNeedsToBeDeleted=" + rowId, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

myPHP.php

```
<?php
    $rowId = $_GET["rowWhichNeedsToBeDeleted"];
    Code to delete row...
    echo "Success";
?>
```

More information is at: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Call your php script by putting the button in a form and placing the php script in the form's action, which is called when the button is clicked.

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
  <td>
    <input type="image" name="delete" src="../web/img/delete.png"/>
 </td>
</form>
```

**Update**
And call the specific function by using the isset method

```
<?php
 function delete()
 {
    function code here..
 }
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
 {
    delete();
 }
?>
```